Combining comint and markdown?
I've recently started using the comint based github chat client https://github.com/chep/copilot-chat.el together with https://github.com/xenodium/chatgpt-shell . It allows a REPL like interaction with github copilot, which is great. However, the answer from github copilot is markdown encoded, but chatgp-shell shows it literally. My question is how could I run "markdown interpretation" on the output from github copilot, before inserting its contents into the buffer? Is there any comint REPL that syntax highlights the output before inserting it into the buffer?

You could use C-hv comint-preoutput-filter-functions to arrange for the process output to go through whatever transformation you wish.
It gets complicated when the process sends the output in chunks, mind -- you really need to wait until you've received all of it, and then process the whole lot after the fact.
I'm not actually certain of the best way to do that, but I suspect one option would be to test comint-last-prompt (checking that (a) it has changed since the output started coming in, and (b) that there is in fact a match for comint-prompt-regexp at that position -- as the interpretation of comint-last-prompt while output is happening is a bit woolly (see the comint-output-filter code for specifics).
If you're doing that, then comint-output-filter-functions might be the more useful hook.
Or there's the comint-redirect* functionality (which you can best read about in the comint source code), but your repl integration would need to be written to use that explicitly.

I recently implemented markdown support in kagi.el, which shares the same shell library with chatgpt-shell. kagi.el uses the markdown-mode package to perform the fontification. This is done in two different places in my package. The code below fontifies the incoming result string with markdown:
(let ((buffer-name (generate-new-buffer-name "*fastgpt-result*")))
    (with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create buffer-name)
      (save-excursion
        (insert result))
      (markdown-mode)
      (view-mode)
      (display-buffer buffer-name)))

Sources:
https://codeberg.org/bram85/kagi.el/src/commit/013749218495e2c1bf2bb203c6b61976963817b5/kagi.el#L383
https://codeberg.org/bram85/kagi.el/src/commit/013749218495e2c1bf2bb203c6b61976963817b5/kagi.el#L247
